# Convert .cda audio file to m4a

Tags: macos, command-line, open-source

I wanted to use ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg -i file.cda file.m4a
```

but I get the error

```
Invalid data found when processing input
```

So how can I convert lots of cda files on macOS?

Comment: If e.g. `file.cda` is a file you have on your HDD/SSD, then you can not convert as CDA files do not contain any audio data, they are just shortcuts to the tracks on an audio disc.

Comment: @user3439894 I realised this, annoying. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't because a .CDA (CD Audio) file is a Windows file, created as a shortcut to a file located on a CD.

The file doesn't contain any Audio data.

I had to rip the CD on my Windows machine, then copy the ripped (located in the Music folder) files onto my Mac.